# MongoDB Error: Exterior shell of polygon is invalid?

Tags: mongodb, gis, polygon

```
db.restaurant.ensureIndex({'deliver_area': '2dsphere'})
db.restaurant.insert({'deliver_area':{type: 'Polygon', coordinates:[[[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1], [0, 0]]]}})
```

raise exc:

Exterior shell of polygon is invalid: { type: "Polygon", coordinates: [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 0.0, 1.0 ], [ 1.0, 0.0 ], [ 1.0, 1.0 ], [ 0.0, 0.0 ] ] ] }

why the polygon is invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a self intersecting polygon:

```
  2      4
  |\    /|
  | \  / |
  |  \/  |
  |  /\  |
  | /  \ |
  |/    \|
 1/5     3
```

You want:

```
{
    type: "Polygon", 
    coordinates: [ [ 
        [ 0.0, 0.0 ], 
        [ 0.0, 1.0 ], 
        [ 1.0, 1.0 ], 
        [ 1.0, 0.0 ], 
        [ 0.0, 0.0 ] 
    ] ] 
}
```

Which is:

```
  2------3
  |      |
  |      |
  |      |
  |      |
  |      |
  |      |
 1/5-----4
```

Comment: Hi, Derick. Thanks for your answer. I have another problem about mongodb geospatial index [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032023/mongodb-2-4-2dsphere-queries-very-slow-using-geointersects)