# Mongodb 2.4 2dsphere queries very slow (using $geoIntersects)?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

mongod.log shows:

```
 {deliver_area: { $geoIntersects:
     { $geometry: { 
         type: "Point", 
         coordinates: [ 116.3426399230957, 39.95959281921387 ] 
     } } 
 } }

 ntoreturn:0 
 ntoskip:0
 nscanned:2965
 keyUpdates:0
 numYields: 2 locks(micros)
 r:136723
 nreturned:52
 reslen:23453
 103ms
```

The collection has about 10k records, where `deliver_area` is one of the fields which is a Polygon(GeoJSON) and has a `2dsphere` index

This is my query:

```
db.area_coll.find( { 
    id: 59, 
    deliver_area: { 
        $geoIntersects: { 
            $geometry: { 
                type: "Point", 
                coordinates: [ 116.3175773620605, 39.97607231140137 ] 
            } 
        } 
    } 
})
```

Explain result:

```
{
    "cursor" : "S2Cursor",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 3887,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 3887,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 5,
    "indexBounds" : {
    },
    "nscanned" : 3887,
    "matchTested" : NumberLong(666),
    "geoTested" : NumberLong(0),
    "cellsInCover" : NumberLong(1),
    "server" : "testing:27017"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The query in the log does not match the query that you run as, the location is different:

`[ 116.3426399230957, 39.95959281921387 ]` vs.
`[ 116.3175773620605, 39.97607231140137 ]`

I also don't think you have reproduced your whole log line, as it just mentions `area` and not `deliver_area`.

However, they are not *really slow*. In the first case, it took 103ms, which in some cases might happen as your server is doing other IO. The second query took 5ms as the `explain()` output tells you.

But what is most striking is that your main criterion is `id: 59`. I don't know what your `_id` field is, but if you set an index on `id` then this should not even have to use a `2dsphere` index at all — unless you have of course many documents where `id=59`. In that case, you could be better off with a compound key on `{ id: 1, deliver_area: '2dsphere' }`.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. My index was compound one.

So I had 2dsphere on location field + Ascending index on zoom field.

I always do query by both fields, filtering by location and zoom and it was really slow.

I tried to make two regular indexes (not compound) and it works fast. So looks like compound index which including 2dsphere doesn't work well or should be used in some complicated way.